# Task Duration and work

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I am trying to carry out following and having difficulty but I cannot figure out why, I am not expert at MS Project.

1. I have one "100% completed" task with duration 35days
2. No Resources have been assigned to this
3. I have set the task type to "Fixed Work"
4. I want to add a "work" of 111 hours to this
5. When I type in 111 hours in work column it changes duration to 13.88days (calculated by 8hrs/d)
6. When I extend the duration back from 13.88days to 35days, it changes the "work" to 280hrs (35d x 8hrs/d)

Why does it do this? I thought "Fixed Work" tasks don't change "work"...

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to set it to Fixed Duration instead.

Fixed Work task type (along with "Effort Driven" checkmark) sets task to calculate its duration on the base of duration of work (111h in your case)